# Como agregar una propiedad a una lista de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, objeto

```
const object = [{nombre:"jesus",sexo:"masculino"},{nombre:"carlos", sexo:"maculino}]

const nuevoObjeto = object.map((e)=>[...e, e.profesion="obrero"])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen sale el error que me aparece cuando intento agregar una nueva propiedad a la lista de objetos, estoy trabajando con react

Comment: `const nuevoObjeto = object.map(e => ({...e, profesion :"obrero"}))`

Answer (score 3):

1. En la definición de tu array te falta cerrar comillas en el ultimo valor (`sexo:"maculino`):

```
const object = [{nombre:"jesus",sexo:"masculino"},{nombre:"carlos", sexo:"maculino"}]
```

2. Para agregar una propiedad usa:

```
array.map((e)=>({...e, other:"otherValue"}))
```

#### EN RESUMEN:

```js
const array = [{name:"jesus", sexo:"M"},{name:"carlos", sexo:"M"}]
const newObject = array.map((e)=>({...e, other:"otherValue"}))

console.log(newObject)
```